# How to call to a method when device clock's minute changes in objective-c

Tags: ios, datetime

I want to do something like this. When my view load I am showing the server time on my view. and what I want to do is when my device clock minute changes I want to call to the service again and get the  server time. Is there any event fire when the device clock's minutes change? Or how can I capture that? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: only one doubt if you change the device time in manually you need to do this function or else

Comment: no not only when manually changed,, when device minutes automatically change I want to call that service and get the server time

Comment: then you need to follow dasdom answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fire an `NSTimer` every 10 seconds and check the minutes in `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: Why every 10 seconds?

Comment: Because it's often enough. Otherwise he/she can use a different duration.

Comment: to fire on the minute change you should calculate the first fire time from the date components and set the duration to 60 seconds